# Find last column matching pattern in each row

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns of 'actions'. How can I find the last action matching a pattern and return its column index or label?

My data:

```
name    action_1    action_2    action_3
bill    referred    referred    
bob     introduced  referred    referred
mary    introduced      
june    introduced  referred    
dale    referred        
donna   introduced
```

What I want:

```
name    action_1    action_2    action_3    last_referred
bill    referred    referred                action_2
bob     introduced  referred    referred    action_3
mary    introduced                          NA
june    introduced  referred                action_2
dale    referred                            action_1
donna   introduced                          NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `apply` function along the `axis=1` and pass the `pattern` parameter as an additional argument to the function.

```
In [3]: def func(row, pattern):
            referrer = np.nan
            for key in row.index:
                if row[key] == pattern:
                    referrer = key
            return referrer
        df['last_referred'] = df.apply(func, pattern='referred', axis=1)
        df
Out[3]:     name    action_1  action_2  action_3 last_referred
        0   bill    referred  referred      None      action_2
        1    bob  introduced  referred  referred      action_3
        2   mary  introduced                               NaN
        3   june  introduced  referred                action_2
        4   dale    referred                          action_1
        5  donna  introduced                               NaN
```

Comment: I think u can do this vectorized in several different ways

Comment: I appreciate the speed of @ecatmur answer, but I don't understand it. I'm not working with a *huge* dataset (should have noted this in my original question), so I appreciate the somewhat more straight-forward approach here.

Comment: If you evaluate the pieces of @ecatmur's answer you'll grok it fairly quickly, it's just written in a much too terse way.

Answer (score 2):

Vectorized method, using `arange` to find the last index, `max`, and concatenation:

```
df['last_referred'] = np.r_[[np.NaN], df.columns][
        ((df == 'referred') * (np.arange(df.shape[1]) + 1)).max(axis=1).values]
```

---

Explanation:

We want to find the rightmost cell in each row that has the value `'referred'`:

```
>>> df == 'referred'
    name action_1 action_2 action_3
0  False     True     True    False
1  False    False     True     True
2  False    False    False    False
3  False    False     True    False
4  False     True    False    False
5  False    False    False    False
```

One option would be [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html#pandas.DataFrame.idxmax), but that gives the first (i.e. leftmost) occurrence.  However, suppose we could replace the `True` values with their column index, we could just use normal `max`. Since `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`, we can do this by multiplying with the integer range `[0, 1, 2, ...]` broadcast vertically:

```
>>> np.arange(df.shape[1])
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> (df == 'referred') * np.arange(df.shape[1])
   name  action_1  action_2  action_3
0     0         1         2         0
1     0         0         2         3
2     0         0         0         0
3     0         0         2         0
4     0         1         0         0
5     0         0         0         0
>>> ((df == 'referred') * np.arange(df.shape[1])).max(axis=1)
0    2
1    3
2    0
3    2
4    1
5    0
dtype: int32
```

One problem, though: we can't tell the difference between `'referred'` in the "name" column and not occurring at all.  Easy fix; just start the integer range from 1:

```
>>> ((df == 'referred') * (np.arange(df.shape[1]) + 1)).max(axis=1)
0    3
1    4
2    0
3    3
4    2
5    0
dtype: int32
```

Now just use this array to index into the column names:

```
>>> df.columns[((df == 'referred') * (np.arange(df.shape[1]) + 1)).max(axis=1).values]
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for size 4
```

Oops! We need to make `0` come out as `NaN` and the rest of the columns to shift over.  We can do this using `np.r_`, which concatenates arrays:

```
>>> np.r_[[np.NaN], df.columns]
array([nan, 'name', 'action_1', 'action_2', 'action_3'], dtype=object)
>>> np.r_[[np.NaN], df.columns][
        ((df == 'referred') * (np.arange(df.shape[1]) + 1)).max(axis=1).values]
array(['action_2', 'action_3', nan, 'action_2', 'action_1', nan], dtype=object)
```

And there you have it.

Comment: This is definitely the fastest option :) If you can understand it :D It would be great for the OP to add some explanations.

Comment: +1 Nice. FYI In pandas 0.12 you'll have to access `values` inside the `[]`.

Comment: I was actually thinking of using cumsum but this is nice!

Comment: Wow, this is **fast**! FYI in master I get `IndexError: unsupported iterator index` :(

Comment: @AndyHayden yes, like @PhillipCloud says you need `.values`.  I've fixed it above as it works for older versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `pandas.melt` and `groupby`:

```
In [123]: molten = pd.melt(df, id_vars='name', var_name='last_referred')

In [124]: molten
Out[124]:
     name last_referred       value
0    bill      action_1    referred
1     bob      action_1  introduced
2    mary      action_1  introduced
3    june      action_1  introduced
4    dale      action_1    referred
5   donna      action_1  introduced
6    bill      action_2    referred
7     bob      action_2    referred
8    mary      action_2         NaN
9    june      action_2    referred
10   dale      action_2         NaN
11  donna      action_2         NaN
12   bill      action_3         NaN
13    bob      action_3    referred
14   mary      action_3         NaN
15   june      action_3         NaN
16   dale      action_3         NaN
17  donna      action_3         NaN

In [125]: gb = molten.groupby('name')

In [126]: col = gb.apply(lambda x: x[x.value == 'referred'].tail(1)).last_referred

In [127]: col.index = col.index.droplevel(1)

In [128]: col
Out[128]:
name
bill    action_2
bob     action_3
dale    action_1
june    action_2
Name: last_referred, dtype: object

In [129]: newdf = df.join(col, on='name')

In [130]: newdf
Out[130]:
    name    action_1  action_2  action_3 last_referred
0   bill    referred  referred       NaN      action_2
1    bob  introduced  referred  referred      action_3
2   mary  introduced       NaN       NaN           NaN
3   june  introduced  referred       NaN      action_2
4   dale    referred       NaN       NaN      action_1
5  donna  introduced       NaN       NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Once I started to understand `melt`, I used it a lot more! It's a pretty big hammer :)

Comment: Like regexp ;) I agree, I just always give the simplest, predictable in speed solution to the OP, and live the exotic ones to you :) `apply` should always be `O(N)` if I'm not wrong. I don't even know how to calculate how `melt` with `groupby` behaves? `O(?)`

Comment: :) My solution is probably too complicated for this case...I'm always in `pandas` mode! @ecatmur's solution will be the easiest to analyze as far as asymptotic performance goes.

Comment: I just timed it on a **huge** DataFrame: ecatmur: 222ms, yours: 1.33s, mine 5.97s.

Comment: Nice! OP should go with @ecatmur's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use idxmax, which returns the first index of the maximum value, or the first index otherwise.  This does require adding an additional 'NA' column, so it's a little messier.

```
revcols = df.columns.values.tolist()
revcols.reverse()
tmpdf = df=='referred'
tmpdf['NA'] = False
lastrefer = tmpdf[['NA']+revcols].idxmax(axis=1)
```